# How to prevent process inside of container to become root?

Tags: docker, containers

When I run `docker run -it -u someuser ubuntu` the container will start with someuser privileges. However, that same process may just run `su` to become a root.
If I had some volumes from my host system mounted to that container, the container would probably be able to do some root-level operations on the host. How to prevent that?
Should I uninstall `su` from the container's image?

Comment: If you're afraid of writes, you could set the volumes to ReadOnly.

Comment: You can't "just run `su`"; it will prompt for a user password and those aren't set in standard Docker images.  I see Dockerfiles frequently go by on SO that go out of their way to set a (very simple, recorded in `docker history`) user password and grant the user unrestricted `sudo` permissions, which in fact has the security issues you describe; but you need to specifically do this in your Dockerfile to have this vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. It seems I had experience with one of these poorly prepared images and I drew wrong conclusions.